# Remove every white space between tags using regex only

Tags: regex

I try to detect spaces between HTML-Tags.

In my case:

```
[...]a lot of code[...]<strong>text with spaces. and dots</strong>[...]a lot of code[...]
```

my goal is to get:

```
[...]a lot of code[...]<strong>textwithspaces.anddots</strong>[...]a lot of code[...]
```

that's it. I tryed something like: `(?<=<strong>.*)\s(?=</strong>)` but it don't give me the spaces which I want to delete. It is important, that I only delete these spaces and no other which may be destroying the code

Comment: you should at least tell what programming language or tool or editor you are using for this problem.

Comment: Are there nested tags? Should comments, `<script>`, `<style>`, CDATA, etc be handled? (And how in that case.)

Comment: I use EditPad 7 for debug all my Regex codes. There are no other nested tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
x="<strong>text with spaces</strong>"
x=pattern=re.sub(r"\s+","",x)
```

Comment: you helped me partially out. I solved it with your and my way

Comment: Can you please post ur solution :)

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is my solution:

```
set(#scrape, $replace regular expression(#scrape, "</strong>\\s|\\s</strong>|</strong>|<strong>\\s|\\s<strong>|<strong>", ""), "Global")
set(#scrape, $replace regular expression(#scrape, "(?<=<strong>.*?)\\s(?=.*?</strong>)", ""), "Global")
set(#scrape, $replace regular expression(#scrape, "&quot;\\s|\\s&quot;|&quot;", ""), "Global")
```